# IE11 hangs during file upload with AjaxFileUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload, internet-explorer-11

Strange problem appeared with IE11 few days ago. The plugin, wich worked good (https://github.com/davgothic/AjaxFileUpload) now doesn't want to. After I choose a file and click "Load" IE deathly hangs. Only kill process helps. I looked into deep jQuery code for posting data and can't find where to put breakpoint before it hangs.
The submitting data is ok, file recieved on server and handler correctly worked, it returns the XML with some info. But no more events (such as "ajaxComplete") called on client after the handler's "context.Response.End();".
Where can I find the problem? It is only in IE11 and on many different machines. IE10 works OK...
Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem, and it seems to be linked to the following security update from Microsoft

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2962872/en-us

Under known issues, they've listed

"Issue 3: After you install this security update, Internet Explorer may become unresponsive in some applications when web forms are being used or when files are being uploaded. This issue affects Internet Explorer versions 10 and 11.

Note We are researching this problem and will post more information in this article when the information becomes available."

After uninstalling this update, our file uploading once again works fine.

Comment: Thanks, dude, I've found that solution also, but remembered to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced this issue as well. I am using a jQuery Ajax call to an MVC controller posting a .csv file. It's definitely an IE 11 issue that isn't resolved. My workaround was to specify "async:false" in the Ajax call to the controller and it solved my issue. I hope this helps someone!
Here is the code I'm using below:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ***,
        data: ***,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
           do something:
        },
        error: function () {           
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hit a similar issue in IE11.  This workaround solves it for now, but of course its locking the browser during the data transmission which is why async: false is deprecated in jQuery on the main thread.

Comment: I think you no longer need to use async: false (Nov, 2017). In fact IE11 gets upset if you use ```async: false``` (goes unresponsive for the entire upload period and shows page un-responsive message at the bottom, but recovers if you leave it alone). Remove ```async: false``` if you find IE11 crashing now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem later with removing the **MS windows update KB2962872**. That sucks, that Microsoft did that bug and took so much time to fix it. I'm still not sure have it been fixed by newer update?

Answer (score 0):

In ran into the same issue with a context a bit different. I share my experience, maybe you could save days of debugging (one week for me) with it.

In my context, I used AngularJS with a .NET server. I tried to use the ng-file-upload extension (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload), but also tried with a more simple FormData javascript object. Same issue occurred:
- In Chrome, everything works fine
- In IE 11.20.10586 on my Windows 10 computer, also no problem
- But with IE 11.0.9600.18059 (Windows 7) and IE 11.0.9600.17728 (Windows Server), impossible to send a file, IE hangs.

After some time and a few new gray hairs, I finally found a hack. Nothing beautiful, but the only way I found to upload a file: I noticed that if I send the request twice one behind the other, but removing the file in the first one, then the second request posted correctly the file!

I still do not have a valuable explanation why that hack is working and not the classic upload, but after debugging and digging a lot about it on the web, I am quite convinced it is an IE bug.

I hope this can help!

Comment: I just found this link that may explain the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688260/angularjs-internet-explorer-file-upload-hanging-after-60-seconds